# Effective method to convert an image file from RGB to YUV

Tags: java, android, opencv, bmp, image-conversion

I am developing an Android application project using Java. I have an image whose extension is JPG or BMP in RGB color space.

I want to convert it from RGB to YUV. I have googled and found that we can achieve it by using the brute force method of using a formula. However, speed is too slow as my application is a mobile application. Is there any other more effective method to convert it?

Answer (score 6):

**This is how you convert from RGB to YUV**

I didn't test how quick this is, but it should work fine

```
...

Bitmap b = ...
int bytes = b.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

byte[] data = buffer.array(); //Get the bytes array of the bitmap
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width, size.height, null);
```

Then do what you want with the YuvImage yuv.

**And this is how to convert from YUV to RGB**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV2,size.width, size.height, null);
//data is the byte array of your YUV image, that you want to convert
yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width,size.height), 100, out);
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: After i follow ur step converrt YUV to JPg . I get a YuvImage object and I used yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight()), 0, fos);

Comment: to save output image. The result image is not full but the resolutio the same as origial bitmap.

Comment: By not full do you mean the picture was cut?

Comment: Yes, the picture was cut. What do you mean by size.width, size.height? is it the b.getWidth and b.getHeight?

Comment: Yes, this is the original bitmap's width and height. replace size.width with b.getWidth() and size.height with b.getHeight(). Let me know if everything works

Comment: Is the picture coming from the camera? If so, make sure that your rotation is correct. to do this, switch the width and height positions when converting to JPG: put b.getHeight() where size.width is and b.getWidth() where size.height is

Comment: @Eran I corrected the question title, can you approve my review? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9114419